# Stalking and harassment

Tags: privacy

I believe my ex wife is redirecting my Yahoo and Google accounts and somehow has access to anything I do online. How can I know if my suspicions are true?

She is director of I.T. of a large company, so I know the knowledge and resources are available. I'm getting tired of having to deal with it. The police doesn't seem to want to look into it. I have even been in contact with the Internet crimes detective with my local sheriffs department. I'm told until she messes with bank accounts they really won't get to involved.

The investigation could take over a year. I need to figure out if and how it is happening to build a case so I can prosecute

Comment: What OS are you running? What exactly do you mean by redirecting? Need some more details as to what exactly is happening when you try to access google or yahoo.

Comment: She ever had the hands on your computer? Opened any suspicious emails after you broke with her? We can think about a simple keylogger on your machine too

Comment: Well, with gmail at least it already does a lot of logging and you can [configure a whole lot](https://myaccount.google.com/security). Namely, you can see account activity (logins, IP addresses of logins, Google's best guess for geographic location, etc.) as explained [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en). That'll really, really help. She may be director of IT, but I'd still be willing to bet she's piss-poor at OPSEC. Because most people are.

Comment: From my anecdotal experience most "Directors of IT" have very little competence by way of hacking.

Comment: @curious_cat Also a good point. I'll amend my previous statement to "it's probably been at least a few weeks since she actually typed anything into bash".

Comment: @ParthianShot Weeks? Years! More likely she comes from a Windows background and thinks "bash" is what you do to skulls in a bar fight. :)

Comment: Get a brand new computer to do all the stuff folks have mentioned (changing passwords and investigating Gmail logs).

Comment: What are the evidences you have to conclude she is able to see everything you do online?

Comment: Proof or else its paranoia. Belief isn't enough.

Answer (score 4):

So if she is hijacking your accounts, she must be maintaining some sort of access. Security questions are easy to guess especially if she's your ex. If you haven't changed your password, now's the time to do that too! Use something that she wouldn't know about.

The easiest way to solve things is to create 100% new accounts. Google also have "two-factor" authentication where you log in with a password and also use an authentication code that is sent to your phone by Google. That way, you need the phone AND the password. Even if she did somehow know your password, she wouldn't be able to log in without the code on your phone.

It's quite possible that she's using very low-key attacks, aka password guessing and security question guessing. As long as she hasn't had access to your computer recently, she's probably not using keyloggers and other malware to snoop on you.

Just for giggles, what have you been noticing?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I know if my suspicions are true?

You can perform regular checks whether someone else apart from you access to your Yahoo/Gmail accounts by visiting them at specific times that you need to write down in order to check the history login (for example, on Yahoo you can check your history login by clicking on *Yahoo account info* -> *Recent activity*).

You can also enable [two-factor authentication](https://www.yahoo.com/tech/how-and-why-to-turn-on-two-step-verification-for-your-96544144259.html) and take other measures inherent to good security practices such as modifying regularly your password, your secret question or simply its answer and so on.

You said she is redirecting your mails: that is easy to check by yourself whatever your message system is. For example on Yahoo Mail you can disable forwarding by *mouse over the Settings menu* -> *select Settings* ->  *Click Accounts* ->  *Click Edit beside "Yahoo Account."* -> *Select POP* -> *Click Save*.

**But** all these measures and eventual others are useless if you do not perform a full scan on your computer to check if there are [spyware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyware) or [key loggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging) installed.

You will need also, in case you are using WiFi, yo [enhance its security.](http://www.howtogeek.com/68403/how-to-secure-your-wi-fi-network-against-intrusion/).

But these are just general hints because no one knows your WiFi settings or your computer/operating system *health*.

As for:

> I need to figure out if and how it is happening to build a case so I
>   can prosecute

That is a question you may ask [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I cant add much to the information above, but I'd also check for forwarding addresses

[Google email forwarding](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en)

[Yahoo Email forwarding](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN3525.html)